# encoding accents in soap lite

Tags: perl, soap, character-encoding, soaplite

I have a perl script using soap::lite that calls a webservice written in Net.
The call works, but the problem is that I need to pass a parameter like

```
SOAP::Data->name('x' => 'àò??\a')->type('string')
```

And the resulting XML is something like

```
<x>\xc3\x83\xc2\xa0\xc3\x83\xc2\xb2??\\a</x>
```

The accented letters are replaced and also the \ becomes '\\'.
I need the parameter to be exactly how is written.
The encoding is utf-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have Unicode literals in your Perl source, you must `use utf8;` and save the file in UTF-8 encoding.